# Javascript "this" in static methods

Tags: javascript, oop, class, static-methods

I have a code like that:

```
User = function(){}

User.a = function(){
  return "try";    
}

User.b = function(){

}
```

​
From User.b() I can call User.a() using:

```
User.b = function(){
    return User.a();
    }
```

but not using this since it's not an instance of user (User.a() and User.b() are something like "static methods").

What i want to do is to be able to call User.a() from User.b() without knowing which is the main function, in this case User.

Something like this to be used in static methods.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In reality there is no methods or static methods in js, there's just functions that are assigned to object properties (functions being objects as well) and they all work the same way. Since you are calling it like `User.b()`, `this` will be `User` for the call.

```
User.b = function() {
    return this.a();
}
```

Comment: What definition are you using of "method" vs "function" when you say Javascript has no methods?  You get a magical extra parameter whose value depends on what object you use to call the function, which seems awfully methodlike.  If your definition of "method" requires the existence of classes, then I submit that your definition may be too narrow.  If there's something else, I'm curious what it is.  Thanks.

Comment: @MarkReed Functions are not associated with anything, you can store the function `User.b` like `var a = User.b` and it changes everything when you call `a()`. A common way to see this is to add event listener like `elem.addEventListener( "click", this.clicked, false )` which can be solved by using [`ugly hacks`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), though many just drop oop at that point and use inline closures. My point is that `this.clicked` is not associated with `this` at all, it's just a dumb function reference.

Comment: I disagree.  Methods in JavaScript are not first-class objects, the way functions are, but that's not the same as saying they don't exist.  Otherwise, C++, Java, Python, and many other object-oriented languages don't have methods, either.

Comment: @MarkReed You are implying that methods are somehow different than functions in javascript and they aren't first-class objects? What does that mean? There is no difference between a method and function, one might call it a method when they invoke a function as a property of some object but it's still a function and a first-class object.

Comment: We should take this to chat if you want to continue. But quickly: based on your `addEventListener` example, your argument for JS not having methods is that function values don't encapsulate their invocants.  I think it shows that while JS has first-class functions (you can pass around function values), it doesn't have first-class methods (those values don't include the invocant). So I'll buy that methods aren't first-class in JS.  But I don't buy that they don't exist, because the magic setting of `this` doesn't make sense without them.

Comment: @MarkReed `this` is set in every function call, does this make all functios methods? The [specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.27) defines method as `method - function that is the value of a property`. So in reality (what I originally claimed), it's just a function. Sure you can call them methods, static methods, classes etc but it only works when the audience really understands in the first place. If the OP understood that it is only a function attached to a property and not a static method, he probably wouldn't have made the question in the first place.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13345/discussion-between-mark-reed-and-esailija)

Comment: @MarkReed @Esailija I enjoyed this discussion!

ActionScript3 (an ECMAScript derivative) offers an interesting example of how we might expect "first-class" methods to behave in a JS-like language. [(reference - search "bound method")](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/learn/as3_learning.pdf) 

In AS3, unlike in JS, expressions that reference a method always evaluate to a bound method, so in `addEventListener('e', foo.bar)`, `this` is always bound to `foo` in `bar`.

Answer (score 8):

The only thing that determines the context of the function is how you call it.

If you call it using a plain identifier (a function name, a variable or a property), the context will be the global `window` object:

```
someFunction();
```

If you call it using a period to access an object member, the context will be the object:

```
someObject.someFunction();
```

---

If you copy a member from an object to a variable, there is no connection to the object any more, and it will be called with `window` as context:

```
var x = someObject.someFunction;
x();
```

If you assign a function as a property to an object, and call it using the object, the context will be the object:

```
someObject.x = someFunction;
someObject.x();
```

---

For your specific case, `User` is a function, which also is an object.

If you call the function using `User.b`, its context will be the `User` object, which happens to be a function in this case. From within the function you can still use `this` to access the context:

```
User.b = function(){
  return this.a();
}
```

Comment: I feel it's worth mentioning that the period is not the important part, since `foo.bar` is just sugar for `foo['bar']`.  When you retrieve a function object from a container and call it, `this` gets set to the container:

`SomeObject.someFunction()`  - `this` is set to `SomeObject`;
`SomeObject['someFunction']()` - the same;
`(SomeObject.someFunction)()` - the same(!);
`(f = SomeObject.someFunction)()` - `this` is set to the global object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have normal inheritance in javascript. I guess you are trying to do something like this:

```
User = function(){
    this.a= function(){
         return 'try';
    }
    this.b= function(){
        return this.a();
    }
}
```

This way User becomes a constructor. Each new instance of User will have acces to these methods. So if you want to create a new instance of the User class, you can use the new keyword:

```
var client= new User()
```

and then you'll have access to all the methods from user using client

```
client.b() //returns 'try'
```

Comment: `a()` ... that will give you `ReferenceError`. Did you mean `this.a()`

Answer (score 0):

Well, functions exist independently of their container objects; they're just values.  So *if* you're not calling them as methods on an object, they inherit whatever `this` is in the calling context.  In that case, expecting them to know about their container would be the same as assigning `User.x` the value 1 and then expecting the number 1 to somehow know about `User`.

However, when you call `User.a()` or `User.b()`, you *are* in fact calling them as methods - methods of the (function object) `User`.  So `this` will be the same as `User`, and `b` can just call `this.a()` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Now js has `class` and `static` keywords, though they are just syntax sugar.

```js
class User {
    static a() {
        return "try";
    }
    static b() {}
}
console.log(User.a())
```