# Using this in statics functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to do something like this:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function () {
      return {
         message: ''
      }
   },
   statics: {
      action: function (msg) {
         this.setState({
            message: msg
         });
         this.forceUpdate();
      }
   },
   render: function () {
      // ...
   }
});
```

But I can't access `this` object of the react class from statics functions. How could I do this?

Comment: You can't not use `this` inside `statics`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript "this" in static methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249037/javascript-this-in-static-methods)

Comment: Ok...so how could I do this?

Comment: The obvious solution would be to remove the statics declaration and declare action as regular method, but I imagine that there must be a reason why you declared it like that in first place. Could you explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to call it like Component.change(), and execute `setState` in this change function.

Comment: `statics` is designed to the static methods, which are called by your component class, but not the component instance. In this context, `this` has no sense. Also, the static methods should not get or set the state.

Comment: It sounds like if you want to trigger a global action and react to it rerendering a component. Maybe you should consider to have a look to Flux or Redux to accomplish this.

Comment: try to use `Component` insidead of this.